# How do we calculate the voltage at a node with an R pullup and RC pulldown?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

In the given circuit how do we determine the voltage V2 at a given time if the switch closes at time t=0?  I think I need to use KCL to determine V2 but not sure about the math that goes with that.

Comment: You are not the only one. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=kvl

Comment: Since you mention you're familiar with KCL, have you tried writing out equations and seeing if you end up with a set that can be solved? You should be able to express the currents in all of the components (R1, R2, and C) in terms of the voltage at V2; if you start doing this but don't reach a set that can be solved, then we can write a far more specific answer that helps cover your specific gap in the solution.

Comment: Is this a school assignment or do you want to skip the hints and just learn the easy answer?

Comment: @mkeith This isn't for a school assignment.  I work with electronics and need a refresher.

Comment: @mkeith and the easy answer would definitely be sufficient

Answer (score 1):

There are two steady state voltages. When the switch is opened, V2 will be equal to V1. Hopefully that is obvious. When the switch is closed, the voltage at node V2 will start to decay toward a new, lower steady state voltage.

V2<sub>initial</sub> = V1

That new final steady state voltage can be calculated using the voltage divider formula.

V2<sub>final</sub> = V1 * R1 / (R1 + R2)

The time constant of the decay, Tau, is equal to the parallel combination of R1 and R2 multiplied by C. You can get this result by applying the Thevenin equivalent circuit at V2, where C is the load and everything else is replaced by the Thevenin equivalent (with the switch closed).

R<sub>parallel</sub> = 1 / (1/R1 + 1/R2)

Tau = R<sub>parallel</sub> * C

The final equation for the voltage at V2 is kind of messy, but conceptually it is simply a decay with time constant Tau, from V<sub>initial</sub> to V<sub>final</sub>.

[image]